# Substracting pointers: Where does this missing level of indirection come from?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of the MS VC compiler on this one. This line compiles fine, but the result I get is not what I'd expect at all:

```
this->Test((char *)&CS2 - (char *)&CS1 == sizeof(void *));
```

The CS1 and CS2 arguments are declared as follows:

```
myFunction(tCS1* CS1, tCS2* CS2) {...
```

tCS1 and tCS2 are structures containing one int and one __int64, resp.

This is meant to check the distance on the stack between my arguments CS1 and CS2, which are both pointers. When I break execution on this line and use the debugger to get the addresses of my two variables, I find that they indeed are 8 bytes away from each other (x64 platform).

However, the result of the comparison is false.

Here is the assembly code generated by the compiler:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [CS1] 
mov         rdi,qword ptr [CS2] 
sub         rdi,rax
```

(then it does the comparison using the result stored in rdi, and makes the call)

Yes, the compiler is comparing the values of my pointer arguments, rather than their addresses. I'm missing a level of indirection here, where did it go?

Of course I can't reproduce this in a test environment, and I have no clue where to look anymore.
I'm cross-compiling this bit of code on a 32-bits machine to an x64 platform (I have to), that's the only 'odd' thing about it. Any idea, any hint?

Comment: Did you see what the size of a void* was, according to your machine? The value MAY (am I remembering correctly?) vary between a 32bit and 64bit architecture.

Comment: Show the variable declarations, please.

Comment: Shakedown >> Yes of course, sizeof(void *) is 8 on my machine, as expected.

This is not the issue. The issue is that for some reason, the compiler decides that it would be a good idea to compare the value of the pointers rather than their addresses, as described above.

When stepping through the execution instruction by instruction, the rdi register ends up containing -10, which so happens to be the value of CS2 minus the value of CS1.

Thanks for replying though.

Comment: @Christophe AGUETTAZ: what compiler are you using? It is possible (though unlikely) that you are encountering a compiler bug. Please supply the declarations for `CS1` and `CS2` though, it will help us diagnose this.

Comment: @Evan Teran: I'm using the x86 version of Microsoft's C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for x64.

Comment: On x64 parameters (first four of them on Windows) are passed through registers, not stack.

Comment: Yes, and they are spilled in their shadow space if needed, so it still (thankfully) makes sense to use a parameter's address, regardless of the calling convention.

Comment: Can you paste the actual dissassembled code and C code, please? Are you sure that you saw a "mov" instruction and not a "lea" instruction? No offense.

Comment: Hi, the C++ and assembler were directly copied/pasted, I only removed the instruction addresses from the dissassembled code for readability.

Comment: Arguably this is a compiler bug, but I think they are within their rights to close bugs about undefined behaviour as wontfix.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [CS1] 
mov         rdi,qword ptr [CS2] 
sub         rdi,rax
```

indicates CS1 and CS2 are not really stack arguments, but rather some global symbols - if I wanted to produce similar results, I'd do something like this:

```
int* CS1 = NULL, *CS2 = NULL; /* or any other value...*/
#define CS1 *CS1
#define CS2 *CS2
```

Of course this is ugly code - but have you checked you haven't such things in your code? Also, dynamic linker might play a role in it.

And last but not least: If you attempt to write code like:

```
void foo()
{
  int a;
  int b;
  printf("%d", &a-&b);
}
```

You should be aware that this is actually undefined behaviour, as C (and C++) only permits to subtract pointers pointing inside a single object (eg. array).

Comment: CS1 and CS2 really are my stack arguments, their addresses/values match those of my argument variables.

Comment: "You should be aware that this is actually undefined behaviour, as C (and C++) only permits to subtract pointers pointing inside a single object (eg. array)."
I always thought it worked the other way around: pointer substraction was allowed in C++ because it makes sense in such cases. But you might be right. However, I wrote the exact same piece of code in a test project and got the expected behavior, so it seems my compiler is tolerating such abuses.

Comment: @Christophe: no, your compiler tolerated it in the specific case when you tested it. There is no guarantee it'll behave sensibly *every* time. Of course, compiler writers aren't malicious, and won't intentionally break your code. But they may sometimes apply optimizations that can change the behavior when you rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: @Christophe AGUETTAZ: Shouldn't taking an address of a stack argument look rather like `lea rax,[rbp+4]` and such?

Comment: This was compiled in debug mode, with all optimizations turned off (as was my test project).

I don't defend the idea of using undefined behaviors that happen to work of course, and I don't like what this piece of code does, but I find it hard to believe that one level of indirection could get dropped because my pointers don't belong to the same array/object. In this specific case, the compiler can 'see' that they don't, but in the general case there's no way to tell if substracting two pointers should lead to undefined behavior or not, so I imagine that the most practical way to implement

Comment: pointer substractoin is simply to substract the pointer values (and divide the result by the size of the pointed type) no matter what.
This doesn't prove anything of course, but that's why I doubt that this really is the issue. Then again, it's the only plausible one that's come up so far.

Comment: @jpalecek: Exactly, and that's the issue. The compiler does not take the argument's address, but its value instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @jpalacek and commenters observed this is undefined and the compiler may be taking advantage of it to do whatever it likes.  It is pretty strange.

This code "works" on gcc:

```
#include 

int func(int *a, int *b)
{
    return (char *)&a - (char *) &b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("%d", func(&a, &b));
    return 0;
}

(gdb) disassemble func
Dump of assembler code for function func:
   0x0 80483e4 :    push   %ebp
   0x080483e5 : mov    %esp,%ebp
=> 0x080483e7 : lea    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   0x080483ea : lea    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x080483ed : mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x080483ef :    sub    %eax,%ecx
   0x080483f1 :    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x080483f3 :    pop    %ebp
   0x080483f4 :    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

and with optimization it just knows their relative addresses:

**(edit: answer was truncated here for some reason)**

```
(gdb) disassemble  func
Dump of assembler code for function func:
   0x08048410 : push   %ebp
   0x08048411 : mov    $0xfffffffc,%eax
   0x08048416 : mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048418 : pop    %ebp
   0x08048419 : ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

The interesting thing is that with `-O4` optimization it returns +4 and without it, it returns -4.

Why are you trying to do this anyhow?  There's no guarantee in general that the arguments have any memory address: they may be passed in registers.

Comment: Yes, it's strange, and with nothing but the info I've given you to go, it's hardly possible to come up with an idea any better than that, but after all if I knew which other piece of info was relevant, I'd probably have the solution. I still think that something doesn't quite add up here, and that there might be a more satisfactory answer. But maybe not.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Just a guess. Is it possible that optimization is putting this arguments into registers, and, as the address of this arguments is being taken, they are being placed in a local variable? Then, just the compiler isn't placing them in the same order as if they were pushed on the stack, so that's why you get +4 and not -4. Is there something in the standard that grants a particular ordering for arguments addresses ?

Comment: The ordering of arguments is defined by the calling convention on the platform.  I don't think the C standard says anything about it.